# Что не так с Яндекс.касса для WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

WoCommerce при чекауте и выборе оплаты через яндекст пишет следущее сообщение

> Что-то не так
>
> К сожалению, заплатить этим способом не получится. Пожалуйста,
>   вернитесь и выберите другой способ оплаты.

Стоит модуль "Яндекс.Касса для WooCommerce" в тестовом режиме, подскажите что делаю не так

Answer (score 0):

Я пробовал этот плагин. Он не работает с последними версиями WooCommerce.

Comment: Есть рабочие варианты?

Comment: Мне неизвестны..

Answer (score 0):

С недавнего времени нужно ставить версию 2.0. Попробуйте.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/yandex-money-checkout/

Comment: вторая версия тоже почему то не работает, пишет тоже самое при оплате и в настройках модуля пишет что ключ не правильный, хотя я его с сайта скопировал